# Getting all entries posted on any given weekday

Tags: entries

Super simple request, not sure if it's possible...

Can we pull all entries that were posted on a Monday, for example? Or pull all entries but group them by the day name they were posted on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't think of a way how to query posts from a certain day, but you can certainly group entries by day they were posted on:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null) %}
{% for day, entries in allEntries | group("postDate|date('l')") %}
    <h2>{{ day }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That may be all I need, thank you - I'm just a bit concerned over how wasteful it is to have to go about filtering the results like this. Might not be an issue in the end though :)